# Get String Value In String Class

Tags: ruby

I'm adding a new method to the String class in Ruby, How can I get the value of the class?

e.g.:

```
class String
 def myMethodName(arguments)
   # here I want the string value
 end
end

puts "Lennie".myMethodName()
# this should return "Lennie" or whatever the value of the string is.
```

Thanks

Comment: Firstly, you don't need to use empty argument brackets in Ruby. They're optional. Secondly, method names are generally underscored, not camel cased.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to access the actual string value by referring to `self`:

```
class String
    def myMethodName()
        self
    end
end

puts "Lennie".myMethodName()
# => "Lennie"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using "self"?

Considering you're adding the a method to String, self refers to the string itself. I suppose if you are not certain you could use "self to_s" to make certain you really get the string value of the surrounding object.

so:

```
def mymethod(args)
  self
end
```

should do the trick